# Nodejs, checking external executable is available?

Tags: node.js

How can I check that an executable is available, on the computer my on which my NodeJS application is installed?

I don't want to wait until I call `child_process.exec()` to find the executable is missing, rather I would prefer to do a preflight check at the application launch, so it can fail early and clearly. I was recently bitten by this, only finding out two days after server launch, so I would like to avoid this going forward.

At the moment I am looking at simply doing `which <command>`, assuming a Unix based environment, and then parsing the output. Is there a better way, possibly more portable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `which` module.  Always search npmjs.com and npms.io.